# What is the difference between a CMS and a Framework? and how to choose between them for certain requirements?

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

I am currently working with Zend Framework and I am extremely happy with it. What I want to know is at what kind of requirements it is better to use CMS's like Joomla or Drupal.

Considering my current project it is a portal application. It is completely made from scratch in Zend. Then some fellow comes and comment that it rather implemented in drupal you could get plugins for the stuff you built by hard efforts.

So I need a guideline for how to choose between CMS and A Framework at the kickoff phase?

Comment: Depends on the CMS and framework of choice, because there are also frameworks ("symfony2" comes into my mind), that can provide you many bundles.

Comment: @Voles The format for links in comments is `[text](url)`.

Comment: I extended my comment, thanks @Polynomial

Comment: No worries. Took me ages to figure that one out myself! I just wish there was a clearer / more obvious resource for StackOverflow's formatting tags, so everyone would just know about them.

Comment: Accept an answer by clicking on the check mark at the left side of answer which worked for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Web Application Framework and a Content Management System?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636259/difference-between-web-application-framework-and-a-content-management-system)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question in your case is whether to use a ready made CMS or to create your own system using a framework. The right answer depends on the following:

- budget
- number of users you will have (long term performance concerns)
- further maintenance
- total number of details (bells and whistles) you want to provide on the site
- implementation with third party/custom APIs
- special/custom features that require high level of freedom (example: StackOverflow reward points and badgets)

As this is a question most of us face pretty often, here are cons and pros of a ready made CMS vs a framework:

**Ready made CMS**

*Pros*

- faster start and development time if your project generally fits in what the CMS provides
- available modules and themes
- backed up by community, meaning that new features, bugfixes, support, tutorials etc. will be provided to you free of charge
- unified set of standards - it's easier to continue working on an existing CMS site than to take someone else's custom application (this is relative, but the point is that in a site that uses an existing CMS most of the things/setup will be familiar to you while in a custom app the previous developer had more freedom)
- security is something you do not need to worry *that* much as in a custom app

*Cons*

- if your requirements are very specific, you will need to override the default workflow of the system; in some cases this can be tricky and will make you spend more time than to write your own
- redundant code in modules/plugins
- performance - a ready made CMS will rarely be as fast as a custom made application
- not suitable for every large website (unless you fit in almost everything that the CMS provides)
- steep learning curve in some cases ([Typo3](http://typo3.org/), [Drupal](http://drupal.org))

**Custom application**

*Pros*

- it's up to you to define the structure and the logic of the application
- app design is made especially for the project you are working on - so there is no redundant code
- freedom to do anything you want

*Cons*

- expensive - in most cases you/your client will need much more money for a custom app
- further maintenance will be harder
- changes and modifications of the structure can be very time consuming
- if you aren't using a CMF you will have to reinvent the wheel in some aspects

---

**Bottom line**

Spend a couple of days and learn something about the CMSs out there, such as:

- [Drupal](http://drupal.org) - my first recommendation; good for medium to big websites; good community; medium/steep learning curve
- [WordPress](http://wordpress.org) - my second recommendation; good for small to medium sites
- [Typo3](http://typo3.org) - enterprise level system; pretty complex, combined with a [framework](http://flow3.typo3.org/) which can be used standalone in projects
- [Joomla](http://joomla.org) - I personally don't like it and do not recommend it because of amateur plugins, but it is popular
- [SilverStripe](http://www.silverstripe.org/)
- [MODX](http://modx.com/)
- [Concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/)

I think that any bigger and serious project, which will have at least 1-2 programmers to take care of the system at all times, should be custom. Exceptions are only if it fits exactly in what an existing CMS offers already.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Good points, but I personally think that projects with 1-2 (or more) programmers still can benefit from using an existing CMS system. Drupal, which is more a combination of a CMS and a framework gives gives you a head start with user management, session handling, caching and lots of other basic stuff which you won't have to implement yourself. With the right configuration, I'd say you won't have much a performance gap compared to a custom built system.

Comment: As I wrote - "Exceptions are only if it fits exactly in what an existing CMS offers already.". If you need to override more than half of the things in a big project, even Drupal is a nightmare. Otherwise, CMS is a great thing of course.

Comment: too comprehensive but also some important points, here is a up :)

Comment: True that. It wasn't to say that I didn't agree with you, but just a comment to say that CMS systems still could be a good match even on larger projects and even though the CMS system doesn't provide what you need by default.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [Difference between a CMS and a web-development-framework](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149260/difference-between-a-cms-and-a-web-development-framework) on StackExchange.com.

A **CMS** (*Content Magagement System*) is used to manage content on a website. It usually provides tools to make this task as easy as possible.

Examples of CMSes: Drupal, Joomla, DotNetNuke etc.

A **framework** is like a set of libraries / classes to build a web application. Many frameworks provide libraries for database access, templating engines etc. This way, you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

A CMS is often build upon a Framework.

Examples of frameworks: CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Kohana...

Answer (score 4):

@Voles mentioned what CMS and Framework is

So your question is "guideline for how to choose between CMS and A Framework "

Want to build a Blog or a simple website ?

Go for Wordpress , Drupal etc.

Want to build next facebook or stackoverflow or app of your own which the current cms is hard for you to learn or is limited with the features?

Then go for some frameworks or custom made ones. Be sure that you know how to build it in the right way.

You can have a look into http://cmf.symfony.com/ also.

Hope that makes clear.

Comment: So i am on correct way, here is and up. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: CMS systems like Drupal and TeamSite blur the line between website and web application.  Advanced functions let you include functionality that others have found useful, but "module development in Drupal" is very similar to, say, "programming with Symfony".  I suspect you could build the next StackOverflow or Facebook in Drupal as easily as you could in Symfony, notwithstanding gaining the initial expertise.  (Any of these tools require you to drink their kool-aid.)

Comment: @ghoti What I meant is Drupal or any cms is made to make in mind for extending it. But at certain point the overhead will be huge that you may want to optimise it for your needs. I am not saying developing is not fast nor you cannot build with it. I have played with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all pros and cons of CMS and Framework , According to me you need to study your requirement at the time of kickoff. List out the modules you want in your application. Now check that how many modules are available in CMS you know about like drupal , joomla , wordpress etc. and also check out that how much customization you need in this available modules as well as custom modules you may need to develop as per your requirement . And if you found out that with minimum customization you can use any particular CMS  and than go for it.

But in case your application may very complex in nature than I suggest go for any MVC framework like Zend , Cakephp , codeigniter etc.

Yes one other thing go with any CMS or Framework that you well versed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Framework is like a library by using this library we can develop new thing.
Whether CMS as name imply its an inbuilt source to manage the content.
Like wordpress we don't need to develop anything.

Answer (score 0):

Framework are the creator of CMS , CMS is basically a Content Management System which focuses on content managing where everything is perfectly setup for you with few lines of code and logics ur website or small app can be developed

Whereas in framework its deeper than CMS everything you have to write from scratch or use existing library which is generally used for making big app. Hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CMSs and MVCs are web application frameworks with coding libraries. CMS is way easier to use for beginners, as it has its pre-made functionalities available, so you will not need complex coding. I found useful information in Wiredelta's article, maybe this will help for you as well: https://blog.wiredelta.com/cms-mvc-framework-comparison/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference**

[CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system): `A content management system (CMS) is computer software used to manage the creation and modification of digital content (content management).`

[Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework): `A web framework (WF) or web application framework (WAF) is a software framework that is designed to support the development of web applications including web services, web resources, and web APIs.`

A Framework offers a basic web application structure with a set of tools, to let you build your own web application, or even a CMS.

**How to choose between them?**

I have been working for many years with different open source CMSs (Much with CMS Made Simple, Prestashop. A bit with Drupal, Wordpress) and frameworks (Much with Symfony, a bit with Zend Framework).
My conclusion is:

- If your requirements can be fulfilled with features of an open source CMS, and there are only a few custom requirements, use that CMS
- If your requirements are complex and/or more custom, use a framework

**Problems when using an open source CMS**

- Plugins often don’t provide all features you need

  - Community plugins

    - Have limited features. If you want to extend the features, you end up copying or modifying plugins, making them harder to update
    - May not be compatible with other plugins or even with the CMS version you have
    - Harder to debug since it's not the clean code of your team
    - May not be fully for free and come with additional costs
    - You spend a lot of time on searching and evaluating plugins
  - Own plugins

    - Limited CMS features (eg. missing dependency injection) may lead to unstructured coding
    - When your plugin gets more big and complex, you may start to ask yourself, why not having used a framework from the beginning
- High learning curve, depending on the documentation, technologies used, and how many architectural rules you have to follow
- Highly dependent on community

  - You may not get a fast answer or solution from the community
  - You may have to debug deep into hardly-to-read plugin or CMS code
  - Own fixes make updates difficult
- Usability

  - Admins may get overwhelmed about default features, and may generate more support tasks for the developer, where a simple content editor for the admin would suffice