# Web Application Framework vs CMS vs Custom Site

Tags: web-applications

I think I have a fairly good idea of what each is (as far as waf vs cms), but I don't have a good idea of which should be used and when.  All web development I have done has been completely from scratch, where I wrote everything and obviously weren't too complex.  Are many sites built from the ground up anymore--is this reserved just for very complex applications?

Comment: I apologize if it's a simple question, but I haven't found much about which is used when or how often.

Comment: See [difference-btw-web-application-framework-and-content-management-system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636259/difference-between-web-application-framework-and-a-content-management-system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CMS:**

Usually used when you are going to have multiple people editing content that know nothing about HTML and need a WYSIWYG to get things done. That being said, certain types of sites that are/need to be database driven for ease of organization usually run on some sort of CMS.

**FrameWork:**

Usually used for web applications as they usually have a ORM that makes managing data from a database very easy. Among many other reasons... (Built in security, user management, etc.)

**Custom Site:**

I usually do custom sites if I won't be getting any or very little data from a database and it isn't a traditional web application. I do this because it is usually faster.

All that being said, you could use any of them for any purpose. It's the built in functionality that makes them better for different things. You question about building from ground up. I would say the more complex the more of a need for a framework. The simpler the site, the easier to write from scratch.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response. I was assuming that the more complex it got (from a data perspective) the more you'd want a custom built site. My buddy asked which direction he should go for a site that had some custom requirements (so no wordpress or anything), but needed to accept payments. I assumed ground up made more sense--whoops.

Comment: Frameworks have value for web applications. Much of the common requirements for webapps (Security, database interaction) is built in so you get up and running faster, but usually they are just as much customization as writing from scratch. I use CFWheels which is much like Ruby on Rails. You don't have to use the built in stuff, but it's there if you need it.